# npm i command is not installing package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

i am trying to install react-barcode package with command npm i  react-barcode
Following log details appears

```
> deasync@0.1.19 install 

D:\BlawalProjects\PointOfSaleSystem\possystem\pointofsalesystemrepository\Pos.React\node_modules\deasync
> node ./build.js


D:\BlawalProjects\PointOfSaleSystem\possystem\pointofsalesystemrepository\Pos.React\node_modules\deasync>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.7.30611.23) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\BlawalProjects\PointOfSaleSystem\possystem\pointofsalesystemrepository\Pos.React\node_modules\deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
npm WARN rc-picker@1.6.3 requires a peer of dayjs@^1.8.18 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! deasync@0.1.19 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the deasync@0.1.19 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-03T19_02_34_764Z-debug.log
```

help me out of these i have tried delete node modules folder and package.lock.json file and then run command npm i but does not work

Answer (score 1):

The error logs you posted say that you don't have Visual Studio and it's development package for C++, which causes the installation of desync to fail.

```
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
```

Install Visual Studio Code so that the package you want to install has the necessary tools it needs to function.

Comment: i have already latest version of visual studio code